# Change default HTTP port

Tags: 18.04

I plan to install Askbot on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. But I already have some web apps installed (using Apache2) so I can't use ports 80 or 8080. How do I change Askbot port to e.g. 8089 or alike? I tried reaching on askbot.org but no one replies or even sees question

Answer (score 0):

You can alter 
`/etc/apache2/ports.conf`
and virtualhosts config to achieve this by changing `Listen` option and port within
`<VirtualHost *:80>`